Continuously facing error - [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]
I’m trying to do some testing with the @solana/web3.js module whilst following along with the SolDev Lessons. However, I am continuously being thrown errors regarding the dotenv module which I have installed with npm just incase (error below). This happens when I change the file extension from .js to .ts and try running t-node  or npx esrun index.ts. It does however work as it should if the file extentsion is .js and I run the code with node. What am I doing wrong here? Sorry if the resolution is simple, I'm only just dipping my toes into all of this.
Just to be clear, I have made a .env file in the project root directory. It includes an environment variable which I know has been formatted correctly.
Thank you in advance.
ERROR
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\development\solana\test\node_modules\.bin\node_modules\dotenv\config.js' imported from C:\development\solana\test\node_modules\.bin\esrun-1715349046260.tmp.mjs
Did you mean to import "../dotenv/config.js"?
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:265:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:933:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1157:11)
    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:383:12)
    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:352:25)
    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:227:38)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:87:39)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:86:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  url: 'file:///C:/development/solana/test/node_modules/.bin/node_modules/dotenv/config.js'
}

index.ts content-
import "dotenv/config"
import { Connection, PublicKey, clusterApiUrl, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL } from "@solana/web3.js";

const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("mainnet-beta"));
console.log(`✅ Connected!`);

const address = new PublicKey(<test solana public key here>);

const balance = await connection.getBalance(address);
const balanceInSol = balance / LAMPORTS_PER_SOL;

console.log(`The amount of sol in address ${address} is ${balanceInSol}`);

package.json content
{
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "@solana-developers/helpers": "^2.3.0",
    "@solana/web3.js": "^1.91.8",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "esrun": "^3.2.26",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5"
}


did you try the suggestion:
Did you mean to import "../dotenv/config.js"?

I just post an answer to an similare question on solana stackexchange
hope this will help others
